# Manipulating command-line arguments in bash

Tags: bash

I want to create a shell script so that I can type

```
gc program_name.c
```

and achieve the same effect as if I had typed

```
gcc -o program_name program_name.c
```

Now, I know how to do this so that I can simply type `gcc program_name` and get the effect:

```
gcc -o $1 $1.c
```

The problem is I want to use tab completion and this method requires me to backspace to delete the extension. (Yes, it's a picayune thing, but I'm interested in learning the general principle behind this kind of argument manipulation, too.)

In other words, I want to be able to have the script *delete* the trailing extension. I'm guessing I can use another variable, but I'm not sure how to say, for example, $name = $1 *minus the trailing extension*.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI -- I strongly advise testing your scripts on filenames with spaces, and being sure to use quotation marks every time you do a parameter expansion. `$1` (or, in the general case, `$foo`) can actually turn into more than one argument if it contains whitespace or glob expressions; you need to use `"$1"` to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
exec gcc -o "${1%.c}" "$1"
```

Comment: That did it, but why? What's the role of the percent sign?

Comment: See ['Parameter Expansion'](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the Bash manual.

Comment: Cool, thanks. The problem with just starting out is you don't even know where to look stuff up.

Answer (score 1):

For unix use

```
name=`basename $1 ".c"`
```

Comment: `$name=` is incorrect syntax; assignments don't have a `$` on the left-hand side.

Comment: The other thing is that the `$1` needs to be quoted; otherwise, filenames with spaces can be expanded into more than one argument to basename.

Answer (score 0):

See whether you can take it forward from the following snippet.

```
pgm=test.c
echo ${pgm%%.*}
```

Comment: Close, but something that follows this example won't work correctly with filenames with spaces -- needs more quotes!

Comment: I got this to work (i.e., to remove the final .c), but I didn't know how to put it in a working script. Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: It also doesn't work correctly with the file name `test.program.c` (but the fix is very simple).